# Create the following pyramid in python

Tags: python

Iv`e been asked to create the following pyramid in python with only using 2 for loops.

1

2 4

3 6 9

4 8 12 16

5 10 15 20 25

6 12 18 24 30 36

7 14 21 28 35 42 49

8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64

9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81

Is there a shorter way only using 2 for loops as apposed to my program?

```
for x in range(1, 10):
    for y in range(0, 1):
        print ('1')
    print("2 4")
    for u in range(1, 2):
        for v in range(0,1):
            print("3 6 9")
        print("4 8 12 16")
    for t in range(1, 2):
        for s in range(0, 1):
            print("5 10 15 20 25")
    print("6 12 18 24 30 36")
    for r in range(1, 2):
        for q in range(0, 1):
            print("7 14 21 28 35 42 49")
    print("8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64")
    for p in range(0,1):
        print("9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81")
```

Comment: Dude you have so many useless for loops that are just printing one sentence, such as `for y in range(0,1):` this only runs once so you can get rid of that for loop completely and just simply have `print ('1')`

Comment: If your code is complete and works, and you just want a review of it, it should be on Code Review.

Comment: Hint what is the relationship between the numbers on each line? What is the relationship between the first number and last number on each line?

Comment: I`m still very new to python and trying to gain an understanding of the language.

Comment: I think they are asking you to create this pyramid without hardcoding the values. Otherwise you don't need loops at all.

Comment: `1*1 = 1` and `9*9 = 81`: go from there... It seems that you've got enough of a grasp of the language to do this concisely; just think about the maths!

Comment: Begin by writing using English and Maths the relationship and then mapping this to code should be straightforward

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna do this more of a code review...

Your first line `for x in range(1,10):` shows that you want to create a loop to iterate through a sequence of code 9 times (10 - 1).

With programming, counting starts from 0, instead of saying `range(1,10)`, you can say `range(0,9)` or even `range(9)`.

This helps make it more readable (I read 9 faster than computing 10 - 1)

Inside this main loop, you've added a lot of for loops... `for y in range(1,2):`. What this means is that it will iterate through the code indented once, as 2 - 1 is 1. Therefore this for loop is irrelevant and you can just simply use `print('1')`.

If we simplify your code taking into account whats said above, we get:

```
for x in range(9):
    print("1")
    print("2 4")
    print("3 6 9")
    print("4 8 12 16")
    print("5 10 15 20 25")
    print("6 12 18 24 30 36")
    print("7 14 21 28 35 42 49")
    print("8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64")
    print("9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81")
```

Isn't that already much nicer and more readable. If you type this into python, it will produce the same result as the code you gave, thats because computationally it is the same, however in your method you have unnecessary steps as mentioned above.

Taking this a step further..
Your code prints out this 'pyramid' 9 times. I think you want to print out this pyramid once, so therefore we will have to remove the initial for loop. What you want to for loop is what is printed. Because there is a pattern behind it, a relationship, you can create a for loop to do this for you. This also helps create a more general-case usability. (So instead of doing this until 9, 18, 27, you can do it until n*1, n*2, n*3 [also a checky hint of what you should for loop]).

Hope this was helpful, comment if theres anything you dont understand!

**EDIT**:
I was just doing some random coding and I found a quite neat way of creating the same result (though it is quite confusing), just wanted to share...

```
for k in [[(j+1)*i for j in range(i)] for i in range(1,11)]:
    print k
```

Comment: Thank you Sylent, that was a brilliant tutorial of not only how to create the pyramid but also understanding for loops in python. I truly appreciate your feedback and I will reference this anytime I get stuck on a for loop again. Thank you kindly and hope you have a super day

Comment: @JadePage my pleasure, maybe its also time to use my actual name on this site as well

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,10):
    for j in range (1,i+1):
        print(i*j)
```

This will print every number on a new line though. If you want to keep everything on the same line, and you don't want to print a list or something, then you might add to a string instead:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    x = ''
    for j in range(1,i+1)
        x=x+str(i*j)+' ' 
    print(x.strip())
```

Comment: or you can do the following to keep the structure `[[j*i for j in range(1, i+1)] for i in range(1,10)]`

Comment: That creates a nested loop with the correct structure. I wanted to stay away from list comprehensions in my answer because I feel like if the OP is as confused as he seems w.r.t. for loops, then list comprehensions will only confuse him further.

Comment: @HamzaHaider printing solution `[print(' '.join([str(j*i) for j in range(1, i+1)])) for i in range(1,10)]`

Answer (score 0):

Four lines, really:

```
for x in range(1, 10):
    for y in range(x, x ** 2 + 1, x):
        print (y, end = ' ')
    print('\n')
```

This makes use of the `start`, `stop` and `step` parameters and will yield:

```
1 

2 4 

3 6 9 

4 8 12 16 

5 10 15 20 25 

6 12 18 24 30 36 

7 14 21 28 35 42 49 

8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 

9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

To get rid of the extra newlines, just change the `print('\n')` statement to `print()`.